# SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6 - Find the username

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sasl

First let me state that the mail server is working fine and users can connect and send email.

Basically there is a local web script connecting into the mail server trying to send mail every few minutes. It has the wrong password. Problem is we don't know what script is connecting in so we are looking for a way to get the username which is being tried.

UGFzc3dvcmQ6 - decodes to Password: so isn't much help. A full log line is below.

```
Dec 11 20:15:37 HOST postfix/smtpd[642]: warning: HOST[x.x.x.x]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
```

Server is running Debian/Postfix/Dovecot.

Comment: I have the very same logs. The IP address alway changes, and requests are coming in from all over the world. It it more likely a break in attempt.

Comment: Good old UGFzc3dvcmQ6. Still trying to log in to my server from all over too after all these years. Just have to ignore it.

Comment: UGFzc3dvcmQ6 is 'Password' encoded in base64, I also see 'VXNlcm5hbWU6' which is 'Username' - been like that for years.

Comment: And years, and years, and years... when, oh when, will they *ever* give up?? I mean, these days, we even _know_ what kind of attempt is being made, even without using a base64 decoder...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We were able to trace the username by using Dovecot itself.

In the `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-logging.conf` config we enabled verbose auth logging using

```
auth_verbose = yes
```

This put the information in

```
/etc/dovecot/info.log
```

Comment: Shouldn't the log be in `/var/log/dovecot-info.log`?

Comment: Mine is in syslog

Comment: This method won't always work - depending on how you setup things / how sasl and auth are done. Best to debug postfix if that is where you see bad auths. Debug peer list is best answer I've found. (below). It can also give you the LAN ip of client if that helps.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to prevent this by setting up SSL and requiring auth attempts over SSL only with

```
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
```

This doesn't present the `AUTH` option to the remote client after `EHLO` and so the spammers/hackers give up because establishing a SSL connection is too much time. They work a numbers game. Now instead it hangs up when they try `AUTH` and I get this in my logs:

```
Jan  7 22:14:27 ip-99-99-99-99 postfix/smtpd[22274]: warning: 91.200.12.140: hostname vps863.hidehost.net verification failed: No address associated with hostname
Jan  7 22:14:27 ip-99-99-99-99 postfix/smtpd[22274]: connect from unknown[91.200.12.140]
Jan  7 22:14:27 ip-99-99-99-99 postfix/smtpd[22274]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[91.200.12.140]
Jan  7 22:14:27 ip-99-99-99-99 postfix/smtpd[22274]: disconnect from unknown[91.200.12.140]
```

Comment: TLS is so cheap now that they try even after TLS only auth enabled.

Comment: I had similar issue with SASL by setting that flag it's gone. and Yes now I'm having connect/disconnect issue for a unknown IP. what you did for that to fix?

Answer (score 10):

If you have [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) installed you can enable sasl (or sometimes called postfix-sasl) in your jail.local (or jail.d) and that should make the annoyances go away.

```
## for me this is in /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/defaults-debian.conf
[postfix]
enabled = true

[postfix-sasl]
enabled = true
```

Comment: Blocking these IPs with firewall rules hurts you more than them. The attacks are generally from botnets and there are millions of compromised machines. Adding firewall rules only slows down your server but does nothing to stop the attacks.

Comment: Fail2Ban uses IPTABLES and (as I understand it) the IPTABLES firewall is built into the Linux kernel and very lightweight. A benchmark (here https://kinvolk.io/blog/2020/09/performance-benchmark-analysis-of-egress-filtering-on-linux/) shows it can handle 10000 rules on a 10G link.  As (for example) the block rules only stay there for 5 mins you would be hard pressed to get 2000 blocked connections per minute given most of them would come from the same bad actor IP. Due to the way TCP works once the syn is blocked you would have to re-negotiate the link (which would fail).  That syn is small.

Comment: @TerryCarmen - blocking with iptables is FAR better than your server having to accept the inbound connection and actually start having a conversation with the other end. There may be millions of compromised machines out there but I've only ever seen a small number of IPs trying to connect at once. Blocking them temporarily usually makes them give up and try bothering someone else.

Answer (score 9):

There are at least two ways of finding the user name(s) being tried.

### Logging SMTP transactions with Postfix

If you know which host(s) your strange connections are coming from, you can enable verbose debugging for them by specifying a [debug_peer_list](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#debug_peer_list) in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
debug_peer_list = 192.0.2.1
```

This will yield, among other things, a message like this in syslog:

```
postfix/smtpd[123]: xsasl_dovecot_handle_reply: auth reply: FAIL?5?user=info
```

You will want to use this setting for very **specific debugging only**, since the **full SMTP session** is logged, including the password.

```
postfix/smtpd[123]: < unknown[192.0.2.1]: AUTH LOGIN
postfix/smtpd[123]: xsasl_dovecot_server_first: sasl_method LOGIN
postfix/smtpd[123]: xsasl_dovecot_handle_reply: auth reply: CONT?5?VXNlcm5hbWU6
postfix/smtpd[123]: > unknown[192.0.2.1]: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
postfix/smtpd[123]: < unknown[192.0.2.1]: aW5mbw==
postfix/smtpd[123]: xsasl_dovecot_handle_reply: auth reply: CONT?5?UGFzc3dvcmQ6
postfix/smtpd[123]: > unknown[192.0.2.1: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
postfix/smtpd[123]: < unknown[192.0.2.1]: Zm9vYmFy
postfix/smtpd[123]: xsasl_dovecot_handle_reply: auth reply: FAIL?5?user=info
postfix/smtpd[123]: warning: unknown[192.0.2.1]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
postfix/smtpd[123]: > unknown[192.0.2.1]: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
```

In this example, a LOGIN attempt for user "info" has failed after the password "foobar" was presented. Like the challenges, you can decode the replies as base64:

```
$ echo aW5mbw== | echo $(base64 -d)
info
$ echo Zm9vYmFy | echo $(base64 -d)
foobar
```

### Logging authentication with Dovecot

Postfix itself does not include a SASL implementation. Traditionally, it was hooked up to Cyrus SASL, but if you are using the Dovecot POP/IMAP server, Postfix can reuse its SASL module.

As you have found out, Dovecot has its own debugging facility, enabled with

```
auth_verbose = yes
```

in its config file, often `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-logging.conf`. The output in `/var/log/dovecot-info.log` will look something like this:

```
Jun 10 13:16:40 auth-worker(14936): Info: pam(info@example.com,192.0.2.1): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?)
```

While there is no host-based control here, there are a number of related options to control what gets logged, specifically whether or not to include the attempted passwords. From the example config:

```
# Log unsuccessful authentication attempts and the reasons why they failed.
auth_verbose = no

# In case of password mismatches, log the attempted password. Valid values are
# no, plain and sha1. sha1 can be useful for detecting brute force password
# attempts vs. user simply trying the same password over and over again.
auth_verbose_passwords = no

# Even more verbose logging for debugging purposes. Shows for example SQL
# queries.
auth_debug = no

# In case of password mismatches, log the passwords and used scheme so the
# problem can be debugged. Enabling this also enables auth_debug.
auth_debug_passwords = no
```

See also the [Dovecot documentation](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Debugging/Authentication) for details.

### About SMTP authentication

As you note, the string `UGFzc3dvcmQ6` in the log message is the base64-encoding of "Password:". What Postfix is logging here is the particular authentication "challenge" that it has sent and received an erroneous reply for. There is also a preceding challenge for "Username:" (`VXNlcm5hbWU6`). However, even for nonexistent users, the failure will only be reported after the password.

The values of the challenge strings are actually unimportant and should be ignored. The first challenge is always for the user name, and the second is for the password. The details about this can be found in the [specification for the LOGIN method](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-murchison-sasl-login-00.txt).

**NB:** Since this is all a bit noodly for just transfering and checking the username-password pair, LOGIN is long obsoleted. The [PLAIN method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4616) works essentially the same but packs both pieces of information into the same base64 string.

Finally, the fact that parts of this conversation are base64-encoded is actually a feature of [SMTP Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954) in general. The idea is to easily allow arbitrary (possibly binary) data to be exchanged between the SASL modules of client and server, without those SASL modules needing to know or care about SMTP itself. You can get an idea of how SASL operates from the [Cyrus SASL documentation](https://www.cyrusimap.org/sasl/sasl/developer/programming.html#client-only-section).